# Hadoop app on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop

How to install Hadoop on Windows 7? I have searched net and couldn't find any reference to it. I don't want to install VirtualBox, get Ubuntu on it and install Hadoop on Ubuntu. Is there any other option?

Answer (score 1):

Hortonworks has a distribution of their Hortonworks Data Platform (HDP) built for Windows. See http://hortonworks.com/blog/install-hadoop-windows-hortonworks-data-platform-2-0/ for info.  I've never run it on Windows 7, but I'd think that it would probably work even though the [listed os requirements](http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0-Win/bk_installing_hdp_for_windows/content/win-getting-ready-2-2.html) are for a server version of Windows.  Worth a try if you just want to try it out and don't want to bother with VM's or building a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide on the Apache Wiki: [how to install Hadoop on Windows.](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows)